# Google Trend Crawler: CSV writing issues

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-crawler, google-crawlers

Below code is Google Trend Crawler that uses unofficical API from "https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends". My code runs fine but one problem is that no one knows the limit to Google Trend Crawler. So if I run my Crawler with List of 2000 or more "DNA", then I have error saying I have exceeded the request limit. If I have gone over the limit, all of my crawled data before the limit will be lost since I am writing to csv at the end of the code. Is there a way to write my data to csv for every loop, so even though I pass the limit, at least I have the data before the limit was reached? Thanks

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import time
import xlsxwriter

pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US,tz=360')
Data = pd.DataFrame()

#for loop check writer path
path = "C:/Users/aijhshin/Workk/GoogleTrendCounter.txt"
#file = open(path,"a") 

#setting index using 'apple' keyword 
kw_list = ['apple']
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, cat=0, timeframe='today 5-y', geo='', gprop='')
Googledate = pd.DataFrame(pytrends.interest_over_time())
Data['Date'] = Googledate.index

#Google Trend Crawler limit = 1600 request per day
for i in range(len(DNA)):
    kw_list = [DNA[i]]
    pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, cat=0, timeframe='today 5-y', geo='', gprop='')

    #results
    df = pd.DataFrame(pytrends.interest_over_time())
    if(df.empty == True):         
        Data[DNA[i]] = ""  
    else:                         
        df.index.name = 'Date'
        df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        Data[DNA[i]] = df.loc[:, DNA[i]]

    #test for loop process 
    file = open(path,"a")
    file.write(str(i) + " " + str(datetime.now()) + " ")
    file.write(DNA[i] +'\n')
    file.close()

    #run one per nine second (optional)
    #time.sleep(9)

    #writing csv file (overwrite each time)
    Data.to_csv('Google Trend.csv')

print("Crawling Done")
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with google specifically, it's always a good practice to append files, if you are crawling to not loose data. Just move your file write into the  loop. BTW where is `DNA` defined?

Comment: DNA is defined previously as list. Can you tell me more specifically to move my file write into the loop? Are you saying I put "Data.to_csv('Google Trend.csv')" next to "time.sleep(9)"? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `Data.to_csv('Google Trend.csv')` after `time.sleep(9)` and change it's  mode to `a`

```
time.sleep(9)
Data.to_csv('Google Trend.csv', mode='a')
```

The mode `a` will append to the end of your `csv` file rather than overwriting it.

Comment: So "Data.to_csv('Google Trend.csv', mode='a')" include to create csv file for my first loop and continue appending the data from following loops? Thanks for the answer btw!

Comment: I just tested writing csv with mode='a' but it has one problem. When Data append csv files, it vertically append the entire data. So after first 10 loops, it has 10 tables vertically that added column to the next for each table. So is it okay to just overwrite it? As long as my last data in writtend on csv, I am happy.

Comment: Hmm i didn't get it what you mean, but if you want to start from over again, i would delete the file and recreate it.